# How I get all blobs and not only the blobs in the root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

How I become all blobs from my azure storage container and not only the blobs in the root?

```
private CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*;AccountKey=*;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test123");

            return container;
        }

        public ActionResult ListBlobs()
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
            List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
            BlobResultSegment resultSegment = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result;
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                    blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob blob = (CloudPageBlob)item;
                    blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                //Directory
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory dir = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
                    blobs.Add(dir.Uri.ToString());
                }
            }

            return View(blobs);
        }
```

The code only returns the blobs on the root directory. But I want also get the blobs inside a Directory.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the various overloads of the `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` method...

Comment: Also, please don't use `.Result`, do `async` and `await` properly or you will have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify `useFlatBlobListing` to true when calling `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` method.